# With Strapi 4 how can I get each users music events

Tags: next.js, strapi

I'm using strapi 4 with nextjs.

In the app strapi holds music events for each user and each user should be able add and retrieve there own music events.

I am having trouble retrieving
each users music events from strapi 4

I have a custom route and custom controller

The custom route is in a file called custom-event.js and works ok it is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  routes: [
    {
      method: 'GET',
      path: '/events/me',
      handler: 'custom-controller.me',
      config: {
        me: {
          auth: true,
          policies: [],
          middlewares: [],
        }
      }
    },
  ],
}
```

The controller id a file called custom-controller.js and is as follows:

```
module.exports = createCoreController(modelUid, ({strapi }) => ({
  async me(ctx) {
    try {
      const user = ctx.state.user;

      if (!user) {
        return ctx.badRequest(null, [
          {messages: [{ id: 'No authorization header was found'}]}
        ])
      }

      // The line below works ok
      console.log('user', user);

      // The problem seems to be the line below
      const data = await strapi.services.events.find({ user: user.id})
      
      // This line does not show at all 
      console.log('data', data);

      if (!data) {
        return ctx.notFound()
      }

      return sanitizeEntity(data, { model: strapi.models.events })
    } catch(err) {
      ctx.body = err
    }
  }
}))
```

Note there are two console.logs the first console.log works it outputs the user info
The second console.log outputs the data it does not show at all. The result I get back
using insomnia is a 200 status and an empty object {}

The following line in the custom-controller.js seems to be where the problem lies it works for strapi 3 but does not seem to work for strapi 4

```
const data = await strapi.services.events.find({ user: user.id})
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting when you `console.log(err)` within the catch block? Probably very insightful. Maybe you do not reach that block, since you are saying you get a 200, but then you definitely would see the `console.log('data', data)`.

Comment: Xzandro thank you for your reply. If the catch block caught the error it would show in the response, because I have passed any error caught to the ctx.body Notice the line ctx.body = err

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for long time, days infact, I eventually got it working. Below is the code I came up with. I found I needed two queries to the database, because I could not get the events to populate the images with one query. So I got the event ids and then used the event ids in a events query to get the events and images.

Heres the code below:

```
const utils = require('@strapi/utils')
const { sanitize } = utils

const { createCoreController } = require("@strapi/strapi").factories;
const modelUid = "api::event.event"

module.exports = createCoreController(modelUid, ({strapi }) => ({
  async me(ctx) {
  try {
  const user = ctx.state.user;

  if (!user) {
    return ctx.badRequest(null, [
      {messages: [{ id: 'No authorization header was found'}]}
    ])
  }

     // Get event ids 
  const events = await strapi
    .db
    .query('plugin::users-permissions.user')
    .findMany({
        where: {
          id: user.id
        },
        populate: { 
          events: { select: 'id'}
        }
      })

 

      if (!events) {
        return ctx.notFound()
      }

      // Get the events into a format for the query
      const newEvents = events[0].events.map(evt => ({ id: { $eq: evt.id}}))

      // use the newly formatted newEvents in a query to get the users
      // events and images
      const eventsAndMedia = await strapi.db.query(modelUid).findMany({
        where: {
          $or: newEvents
        },
        populate: {image: true}
      })


     return sanitize.contentAPI.output(eventsAndMedia, 
                     strapi.getModel(modelUid))
    } catch(err) {
      return ctx.internalServerError(err.message)
    }
  }
}))
```